# Why would someone buy stocks that don't pay dividends?

Tags: stocks

I'm very confused about the reasoning to buy stocks without dividends. What can I use stocks for other than selling, if they don't pay me dividends?

Comment: So I would buy a stock because I expect the firm to pay dividends in the future?

Comment: Are you aware that on the ex-dividend date, share price is reduced by the exact amount of the dividend, creating an equal yet opposing capital loss?  Dividends received in a non sheltered account are tax inefficient.  Receiving a dividend does not provide  total return - only share price appreciation achieves that.